# How do I get my discord bot to repeat part of what i say?

Tags: python, discord

I'm pretty new to the discord.py and python community so any advice whether or not it has to do with the question would be great. I wanted to make my bot repeat part of what anyone says but it doesn't work at all, and it stops other commands form running. This is my code,

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user and message.content[:9] == "-chastise":
        if message.content[10:] != "@Johnny Wobble#1085":
            print("confirmed stage 2")
            responses = [
                f"Were you being bad {message.content[10:]}? or are you just slow?",
                f"How many time have I told you {message.content[10:]}! Don't be slow and eat your cereal!",
                f"When I looked up a picture of bad people who don't do their homework, I see a p"
                f"icture of you! {message.content[10:]}"
            ]
            await client.delete_message(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(responses))
        else:
            print("confirmed stage 3")
            await client.send_message(message.channel, f"Ah, I see you {message.author.mention}, trying to turn me agai"
            f"nst my master eh? Well I say no! I cannot believe you would think that I would ever do that to the all-po"
            f"werful Max (Gordon)!")
```

|what is supposed to happen|

(anyone): -chastise @personxyz#1234

(bot): Were you being bad @personxyz#1234? or are you just slow?

[then it deletes the first message, but I think I already figured that out]

Answer (score 0):

After looking through your code, seems like you just need to bot to repeat mentions rather than repeat strings.

You can do `message.mentions` to get a list of mentions in the current message (empty if theres no mentions).

In your code, you could do:

```
# After checking there is at least one mention in the message.

# Fetch the first mention in the list, get a string that can mention the user.
mentionUserStr = message.mentions[0].mention

# Fill in the mentions inside the responses
responses = [
    f"Were you being bad {mentionUserStr}? or are you just slow?",
    f"How many time have I told you {mentionUserStr}! Don't be slow and eat your cereal!",
    f"When I looked up a picture of bad people who don't do their homework, I see a p"
    f"icture of you! {mentionUserStr}"
]

# stuff
```

If you need part of the actual user's message, trim it, assign it to a variable and place in respectively in the string array as what I did above.

Finally,

```
await client.delete_message(message)
await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(responses))
```

Notice how you are trying to get the message's channel after you delete it, though the doc does not say that `message` would be null after deletion, but to be on the safe side:

```
await client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(responses))
await client.delete_message(message)
```

Use the message first before deleting.

Also, might want to check if the bot has enough permissions to delete other's messages first before trying to do so.

Comment: Ok thank you and yes it does have to proper permissions to delete messages.